# Difference between @ and # symbols in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This may be a very obvious question, but I can't find anything online about some excel symbols I see being used in specific tables/non-tables.

What are the main differences and uses for the '@' symbol and the '#' symbol, primarily in between the '[]' brackets?

I believe that I understand the [] brackets are used to identify a workbook, however in the cases that I've seen they are used in this manner to reference a column header:

```
=IF([@Act]="4012A",40121,VALUE(LEFT([@Act],4)))
```

or

```
=SUM(Table6[@[Debit Amount]:[Credit Amount]])
```

I'm expecting to get an answer that says that the @ symbol return a value as a number, whereas any reference within the [] without the @ symbol will return a text string or the original data format from the referenced cell/array.

Still unsure about the addition of the '#' symbol within a formula, so any answer will help.

Comment: It's structured references with tables: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e

Comment: This other answer may help you: https://superuser.com/questions/501691/what-does-the-bar-foo-operator-do-in-excel-in-particular-the-at-sign